# Preview files from terminal like gnome-sushi does in nautilus

Tags: command-line, scripts, gnome-terminal, previews, gnome-sushi

I know that there are commands like `cat`, `less` or even `xdg-open`, but I really like the convenience of just previewing. GNOME Sushi doesn't seem to support commands from the terminal.

Maybe a similar application can do the job or even writing a script? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in [`ranger`](https://ranger.github.io/). It is a terminal-based file manager that uses a three-columns layout. The left column shows the parent directory, with the current directory highlighted, the middle column shows the contents of the current directory and the right column shows a preview of the selected item.

[image: ranger in terminal]

In the above screenshot you can see that I am inside the `/var/log` directory (left column) and I have selected the `faillog` file (middle column) which I am previewing (right column).

You can install `ranger` by running:

```
sudo apt install ranger
```

Start it by opening a terminal and running:

```
ranger
```

You can move around using the keyboard arrows or VIM-like shortcuts (<kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>). You can open a file in the selected application by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>. You can close `ranger` by pressing <kbd>q</kbd>.

More information can be found in the [Official user guide](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Official-user-guide).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I downloaded ranger to check it out. Although I can preview all kinds of text files I still can't preview photos or videos and that's a bummer. Maybe I need  to tweak it a little bit.

Comment: It is actually possible to preview images and videos in `ranger`, but how easy the configuration of this setting is depends on the terminal you use. See [this](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Image-Previews) for enabling image previews and [this](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Video-Previews) for enabling video previews.

Comment: I use gnome-terminal so I can't really display images with ranger. It seems like there is not really a good solution to my problem. Thank for your time. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Nowaday you can use `sushi` directly in your terminal with, e.g.:

```bash
$ sushi ./something.jpg
```

It can do exactly only that, and it's great:

```bash
$ sushi
The launcher takes exactly one argument

Usage:
    sushi FILE
    Opens FILE in a NautilusPreviewer window.
```